# How to get current position of an object using Blender's Python API in BGE?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I'm updating an objects location using a Simple Motion Actuator. I see it move on the screen.

In Python I want to get the objects' current position.

```
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
obj = scene.objects['Sphere.002']     # The object the actuators are defined on

obj.position
obj.worldPosition
obj.localPosition
```

I've tried these three methods of the object, but all of them only show the **original position** of the object, not the **current position** based on the changes made by the logic bricks.

---

Here's another example of what I'm doing wrong, it seems to be the same problem.

I have a text object, I've defined a text game property that I increase or decrease with a keyboard sensor. When I print the value of the text it only prints the original value of **0.5** not the value I see on the screen.

[image]

```
print(bge.logic.getCurrentScene().objects['mytextobject'].text)
```

This always prints the original value, not the value that is updated from the logic bricks. This must be a trivial error, but I can't figure out what to do. I've looked at all the properties of the `scene.object` and I don't see anything that looks like it might give me the expected result.

Comment: What changes have you made?. [obj.worldPosition](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=world%20position#bge.types.KX_GameObject.worldPosition) = current world position. Maybe ``'Sphere.002'`` never move. Please add some images.

Comment: Be aware controllers get executed BEFORE the active actuators run.

Answer (score 1):

When are you reading the value?  If you've assigned it to a variable, it might be reading the initial value, and ignoring any updates.

You'll need to update the value periodically.  Possibly using an **Always** sensor, with a skip, if desired.  Or at certain times within the game;  collision with another object, for instance.

You may need to access appropriate coordinate within it's location vector:  **obj.pos.x**

[image: Location]

Comment: It's during the execution of the game that I don't see the changes. I print this value out constantly: `bge.logic.getCurrentScene().objects['Sphere.002'].position.z` and the object `Sphere.002` moves on the screen in response to my keyboard (using logic bricks). But it always prints the same original value of 3.25, where it starts on the screen.