# Mathutils Vector Raycast

Tags: game-engine

I have an object I wish to cast a ray from, casting using a mathutils direction vector.

The only problem is that I cannot seem to figure out how to find the 3D position (needed for the rayCast function) from the vector.

If anybody could help, I'd be terribly grateful for it. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you wish to cast the ray from the objects origin? A specific point on the object?

Comment: from the origin, using the vector

Comment: This question https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/95324 and this answer should contain enough info https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39678.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say it's a mathutils direction vector. I know the origin of the object casting from, but need to use the direction vector to get a position in a certain direction from that origin.

Comment: It seems you want to measure from one point to another. What points are that?

Comment: Sorry, I think I was unclear. I don't need to measure distance, that'd just be pythagoras.
My intent is to take a vector V and 3D point A, then use them to find the coords of a point x distance away from point A in direction V

Comment: To points in space A and B the direction vector A to B  is D = B - A.  The distance from A to B is D.length. Normalize it and  and any point from A traveling x along D is P = A + xD.  ( `d = a + x * d.normalized()`  )

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but had to work on a similar situation tonight.

All you need to do is add the vector to your 3D point A(which should also be a vector pointing from your object to the origin point of the scene). This should give you a target point in 3D space.

```
target_point = point_A.worldPosition + vector
```

If you want to change the distance away from your point_A origin, you need only alter the magnitude of your vector:

```
vector.magnitude *= 5 # 5 times the vector length
```

or

```
vector.magnitude += 30 # 30 Blender units greater than your original vector
```